# Cognito user pool csv header unavailable in us-east-2, is there a workaround?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

- Cognito user pool - Created around April 2018

  - User count is only 46
  - Other [limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html) are well above current usage
- Region: us-east-2

The [GetCSVHeader API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetCSVHeader.html) is failing even through the console since 2 days ago.

- Console created a `headers.csv` file that only contains the string: "There was a problem downloading CSV headers. Please try again."
- API error is: "An error occurred (InternalErrorException) when calling the GetCSVHeader operation (reached max retries: 4): Internal server error."

**Is there a workaround or alternative to get this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: You should definitely report this to AWS Support, because if it's an outage or a bug they'll be interested in getting it fixed.

However as a workaround, I suspect you could just author it yourself. From the [documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-using-import-tool-csv-header.html), the format is fairly transparent:

```
{
  "CSVHeader": [
    "name",
    "given_name",
    "family_name",
    "middle_name",
    "nickname",
    "preferred_username",
    "profile",
    "picture",
    "website",
    "email",
    "email_verified",
    "gender",
    "birthdate",
    "zoneinfo",
    "locale",
    "phone_number",
    "phone_number_verified",
    "address",
    "updated_at",
    "cognito:mfa_enabled",
    "cognito:username"
  ],
  "UserPoolId": "USER_POOL_ID"
}
```

Specifically, the `CSVHeader` section is just a list of active attributes in your user pool. The full list of built-in attributes can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html), and any you've created will be in the form `custom:ATTRIBUTE_NAME`.

Comment: Thanks will try it. I only have basic support (ie: tech support not included) in the account so sadly, I can't report it.

Comment: After reporting feedback on the documentation, since even the error was not documented, it now works again :D